The natural generalization of Bottema's theorem
Recall Bottema's theorem. I think there is a simple natural generalization of it.
Claim:

In any quadrilateral $ABCD$ with fixed side length $CD$ construct squares on sides $BC$ and $AD$. The midpoint $M$ of the line segment that connects the vertices of the squares opposite the vertices $C$ and $D$ is independent of the location of $C$ .


Proof is much the same as proof for classical Bottema's theorem but in order to finish the proof I need to show that length of the orthogonal projection of the side $CD$ on the side $AB$ is the same no matter where vertex $C$ is. How can it be done?

Why don't you mention your interesting old question here about the similar question for a triangle instead of a quadrilateral ?

@JeanMarie Well I am strongly against self-promotion :-)

I like the humor, but recognize that this is not the issue ! In research in general, people systematicaly mention their previous works especialy when there is a direct link with their present-day workings. Moreover it can give ideas to people wanting to solve the question.

FYI: I mention, and dynamically illustrate, this generalization (though with the name "Potema's Theorem") at the beginning of this answer to a question about theorems involving two squares. The diagram indicates how the fixed midpoint's location derives from the lengths and relative inclinations of the opposite sides of the quadrilateral.

@Blue Thank you for informing me.
